# Ember JS: Customizing adapter to include multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I currently have a database with 2 objects:

1. Role
2. Permission

ONE Role can have MANY permissions. I currently have my Role adapter setup as:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
  namespace: 'v1',
  host: ENV.APP.API_HOST,
  authorizer: 'authorizer:application',
  pathForType: function(type) {
    return 'staff/roles';
  }
});
```

By default, when a Permission is added to a Role, it generates this request:

Request:

```
PUT /v1/staff/roles/1
```

Body:

```
{
  "name": "name_of_role"
  "permissions": [
    {
      "id": "3", 
      "name": "name_of_permission"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I'd like to customize my adapter to produce a request that looks like this instead:

Request:

```
PUT /v1/staff/roles/1/permissions/3
```

Body:

```
<None>
```

Can someone please tell me how I can go about doing this? Updating the server api to accommodate Ember JS is unfortunately not an option.

**UPDATE:**

Based on Ryan's response, here's a (I'll call it messy) workaround that did the trick for me.

Open to suggestions for making this more elegant:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
  namespace: 'v1',
  host: ENV.APP.API_HOST,
  authorizer: 'authorizer:application',
  pathForType: function(type) {
    return 'staff/roles';
  },

  updateRecord: function(embestore, type, snapshot) {
    var roleID = snapshot.id;
    var permissionID = snapshot.adapterOptions.permissionID;
    var url = ENV.APP.API_HOST + "/v1/staff/roles/" + roleID + "/permissions/" + permissionID;

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      Ember.$.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: url,
        headers: {'Authorization': 'OAUTH_TOKEN'},
        dataType: 'json',
      }).then(function(data) {
        Ember.run(null, resolve, data);
      }, function(jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.then = null; // tame jQuery's ill mannered promises
        Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
      });
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find it in the Ember documentation but there is a [universal ajax method](http://pulkitgoyal.in/add-params-ember-datas-restadapter-ajax-requests/) attached to adapter that you can override.

So in my adapter to fit our auth scheme I've done this:

```
 export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
     host: ENV.host,
     ajax: function(url, method, hash){
        if(hash){
            if(hash.data !== undefined && hash.data !== null){
                hash.data.sessionId = this.getSessionId();
            }
        }else {
            hash = {
                data: {}
            };
            hash.data.sessionId = this.getSessionId();
        }
        return this._super(url, method, hash);
    },
    getSessionId: function(){
        return window.sessionStorage.getItem('sessionId') || {};
    }
}
```

This attaches the sessionId to every ajax call to the server made though out the entire application.

Changing it to modify your `url` based on the `hash` arguments passed in shouldn't be an issue.

My version of ember is 2.3.2 but I'm on the latest stable(2.5.2) version of ember-data and this is still working great in case you are worried about the age of that blog post I found.

Comment: Thanks for the great pointers @ryan. Will add an Update to my answer with the solution used. Followed your direction fairly closely.